# How to get a list of all open windows in KDE from CLI?

Tags: window, kde-plasma

Is there a way to get a list of titles of all open windows in KDE from CLI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
wmctrl -l | awk '{print $4}'
```